# Script only works correctly with one of two buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my jQuery Button. So I have 2 buttons the nexButton and the bacButton. The code that I will show you works perfect on the nexButton but it doesn't work that well on the bacButton.

(important !) this is a link to a video where you can see what is going on:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4huQ5CRNc4

As you can see when I hold the mouse on the nexButton it changes the opacity and it stays the same until I get my mouse of the button. But when I hold the mouse on the bacButton it changes the opacity of the button but it just changes back to the old opacity (what souldn't happen and just stays the opacity until I get my mouse of the button).

Here is the code that I use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nexButton, #bacButton').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: '1'},'fast'); 
    });
    $('#nexButton, #bacButton').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: '0.7'},'fast'); 
    });
});
```

My buttons:

```
<img id="bacButton" src="arrowhead9%20(2).png">
<img id="nexButton" src="arrowhead9%20(2).png">
```

Can someone fix this code for me? because I can't make it work and I also tried other combinations and other code.

Comment: add your html for the buttons too. and your video is private.

Comment: Use http://jsfiddle.net/ to replicate the result. You will receive better answers.

Comment: I don't understand why don't you use CSS `:hover` with opacity transition instead of javascript?

Comment: Because I want it to more when I hover it and why not just put I all in one script and not over css and javascript. And still why doesn't it work (because it sould work)

Comment: Really can't understand your last sentence. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: The code you provided works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/8rLgcaeL/1/ your issue must be elsewhere in your code

Comment: Do you have other `mouseenter`, `mouseleave` events on those buttons? Maybe some `css` `:hover` rule on them that messes with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the jQuery [fadeTo](https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) function

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // set fade animation time in ms
    var fadeTime = 250; 

    // set initial opacity
    $('#nexButton, #bacButton').fadeTo(fadeTime, 0.5);

    // change opacity on hover
    $('#nexButton, #bacButton').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo(fadeTime, 1);
    });
    $('#nexButton, #bacButton').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo(fadeTime, 0.5);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/azizn/vbh85j3h/)

I would still advise going for a CSS approach since it is native and more reliable

```
#nextButton, #bacButton {opacity:0.5; transition:.25;}
#nextButton:hover, #bacButton:hover {opacity:1;}
```

Make sure to add vendor prefixes for cross-browser compatibility

Comment: Okey it is getting even more weird. But at first I tried your code Aziz and it still does act strange. So at your advice I tried the :hover in css and now the bacButton doesn't even change to it's new given opacity. (the nexButton is still just working fine..)

Comment: My best guess would be that there is an element ABOVE the back button (with a higher z-index) that could cause this weird behaviour, it is as if the mouse is not detecting the full size of the button - sharing the entire code will be helpful

Comment: I already thought of that and I changed it's z-index to 10 (so above all the containers etc.) but it didn't help :(

Comment: z-index does not work unless the element has a `relative` or `absolute` `position` - try `position:relative; z-index:10;`